# Change URL display but stay on the site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know this has already been asked but I never found an answer that worked for me. I tried understanding the `mod_rewrite` myself but I always got stuck. I searched a lot online and I've read the Apache documentation, Stackoverflow posts and a few tutorials (addedbytes/ smashingmagazine/ selfhtml/ and so on...).

Every URL the user sees looks like this at the moment: `www.example.com/text/show/1` The number at the end varies, because the texts are numbered by the CMS. I would like to show the user an URL like the following: `www.example.com/home` while he visits `www.example.com/text/show/1`. Of course this should be possible on other sites as well. (Hint: The pages aren't numbered continously.)

I want to rewrite the URL the user visits, using the .htaccess. The user should stay on the same page but he should see a nicer URL. I don't have any file extensions, because I'm using a CMS from a coworker that works without them.

This is my .htaccess:

```
# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect old PHP-pages to new pages
Redirect /fancy.php http://www.example.com/text/show/6
Redirect /foobar.php http://www.example.com/text/show/12
# Here are a few more redirects

# URL rewriting
RewriteRule ^home/?$ text/show/1 [NC,L]

# Skip the bli and bla directories
RewriteRule ^(bli|bla)($|/) - [L]

# Skip existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite the URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I need the redirects because some pages of our old version of the websites where we used no CMS are still available online. The last parts (After `Skip the bli...`) are given from the CMS so I can't change them. I enabled the `mod_rewrite` on the apache so this should be the problem. I also reloaded and/ or restarted the apache after my changes.

Everything else works well but the `RewriteRule ^home/?$ text/show/1 [NC,L]` doesn't. Can somebody please tell me how I can fix this?

PS: I'm testing this on a local domain so I don't make any mistakes online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably does not work because of the nature of your CMS. Your CMS is rewriting all requests to `/index.php` and is then probably using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal (which contains the URL of the request, ie. the visible URL in the address bar) to route the request.

If you are rewriting `/home` to `/text/show/1` (internally) then the request is `/home`, not `/text/show/1`, which your CMS is expecting. I would guess that your CMS simply does not know how to route `/home`.

Since your CMS is already using "pretty" URLs, this is something that would need to be configured in the CMS itself (if it is supported).

Alternatively, you could *externally redirect* from `/home` to `/text/show/1` - but then the user will see `/text/show/1` in the address bar, which is not desirable.

---

Aside: As a general rule, you should not mix mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) directives in the same .htaccess file. Since they belong to different Apache modules, the order of execution might not be as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I guess I'll speak to my coworker and we'll check if there's a solution to configure this in the CMS.